# Gradle & SpringBoot - Error cant resolved

Tags: java, git, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to run my first application with SpringBoot & Gradle. I am using git as version manager.

I create my project via this online tool : https://start.spring.io/

[gradle setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81oVc.png)

Then, I push my project via Git on my Bitbucket Repository :

[my bitbucket architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L72XF.png)

Next, I import my project from Git via eclipse eGit plugin. That's my basic project in eclipse IDE :

[project eclipse explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8j5G.png)

My problem is concerning Gradle. I have a depencies problem (I believe) and my project doesn't compile correctly.

[my gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVwp3.png)

I tried different way :

- Add in build.gradle : compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') AND/OR compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot')
- I run : ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies

Nothing works. I need some advices to start with these news technos' =) Thank you very much mates!

Comment: first, try to execute `./gradlew clean build` outside your IDE (Eclipse), in any terminal : if you get error message please add it (with stacktrace if available) into your question

Comment: This command works well. It seems to be an eclipse issue?

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/42/4/1539848535-capture-du-2018-10-18-09-38-30.png

Comment: maybe an issue with your Eclipse/ eGradle plugin version : which version are you using?

Comment: Please edit "enter image description here".

Comment: I find solution... Was weird but it works, don't really know why but! Name in my settings.gradle (project) had camel while my project didn't in my eclipse...

Not really interesting but if it could help! Thanks anyway mates =)